# Admin adding options

Tags: 10, notifications

I **may** end up with an answer of "rather than Notify, use" and I am open to suggestions.

So I have Drupal 10 with the [Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify) extension. My use case is that users can opt to select notifications on new content in selected content types because some of them are loosely time critical. Some users would prefer instant, but tough.

The website is set up with the admin creating accounts due to the small userbase. Adding users will be occasional unless we expand to other remote locations or teams internally. I want to pre-load the Notify categories on request though, as some of the userbase will get confused.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possibly https://www.drupal.org/project/eca

Comment: I would use eca. It takes some time to learn, but is an excellent module for building out processes.